# Scroll to top Javascript code not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I copied and pasted the code for scroll to top in my webpage from the following website:

http://jsfiddle.net/neeklamy/RpPEe/

Even though the scroll to top button does not showing up,
my webpage source code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Rough</title>
<style type ="text/css">
.scrollup {
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
position: fixed;
bottom: 50px;
right: 100px;
display: none;
text-indent: -9999px;
background: url('icon_top.png') no-repeat;
background-color: #000;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
    }
});

$('.scrollup').click(function () {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 600);
    return false;
});

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Top of the page</h1>

<article style="height: 1000px">
<p style="margin-bottom: 600px">Scroll down the page&hellip;</p>
<p>Then click the box.</p>
<a href="#" class="scrollup">Scroll</a>
</article>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: works like a charm for me, what browser are you in?

Comment: @whitebox google chrome

Comment: it works fine for me in Chrome, Firefox and IE 11

Comment: Working perfectly for me, too! :)

Comment: Working for me in Chrome as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing jQuery, add the script tag like so:

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

or add it locally by downloading the library and adding it to your project files.

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nayish/uLt7guvg/2/

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the 'icon_top.png' file. You must have that image in the same folder as the .html file.